# Why comparing checked attribute not working for checking at least one checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I did something like this for checking all checkboxes are checked:

```
var container = $("#container");
$(container).find("input[type='checkbox'][checked != 'checked']").length == 0
```

But when I am using checked attribute for checking at least one box is selected it is always giving me length = 0, my code for this is as follows :

```
 $(container).find("input[type='checkbox'][checked = 'checked']").length > 0
```

Difference is in 1st code snippet I used '!=' and in 2nd I used "=". So why it is not working in 2nd case?

I know I can get it working by using:

```
  $(container).find("input[type='checkbox']:is('checked')").length > 0 
  $(container).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0
```

But still wanted to understand why above stuff is not working :O

I dont know if this is the cause, but I have select All checkbox and  which is implemented by setting 'checked'  Attribute value for all checkboxes by

```
$(container).find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked","checked")
```

And for unselecting all checkboxes  I have :

```
$(container).find("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("checked","checked")
```

And might be because I am removing attr checked while unselecting, when I click on checkbox again through UI I dont get its checked attribute value. Is this the case?

Comment: check ur container whether it is a class or id ??

Comment: It is an Id and is same in both the cases.

Comment: Works fine for me, check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fLeC/)

Comment: notice that if you have checked="true", the checkbox still checked but your condition no longer return true

Comment: Please check the edits to question.

Comment: u say container is an id and u use $(container) jquery lik this ??.. it should be $('#container')

Comment: I am sorry I dint explain it in question, but container is an variable which contains jquery element. 
var container = $("#container");

Answer (score 0):

then try this one

```
$('#container').find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0
```

or

```
$.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function() {

alert('Checked')

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/hAv3z/